# How to create an object and save as new instance in another model

Tags: django, django-models

My model B has Model A as PK. In this question i am creating a model A.
In my form clean method, i did the code below. I got an error:
"save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'transac'."

I understand that this may be because i am saving 2 instance of transac. 1 coming from the form itself, and another here in the clean method. But i dont know the right way to do it...

```
def clean(self):
    from Ticketing.models import Ticket,Transaction
    cleaned_data = super(TransactionForm, self).clean()

    computerid = cleaned_data.get('id_comp')
    newticket = Ticket(transac=Transaction(id_comp=computerid))
    newticket.save()

    return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you shouldn't be doing this in `clean()`. That is called to check whether or not the form is valid, so you would be creating your Ticket even if the form was invalid. The code needs to go either in the save method, or in the view itself.

Secondly, you need to use the instance of Transaction that is created by the form save, rather than instantiating a new - and, as the error says, unsaved - one.

So, assuming you did this in the view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    transac = form.save()
    newticket = Ticket(transac=transac)
    newticket.save()
    return redirect('wherever')
```